# Ubuntu 17.04 installation, ACPI errors, graphics issues, mouse doesn't respond sometimes

Tags: nvidia, graphics, uefi, live-usb, acpi

After figuring out my other issue ([Can't install Ubuntu/Ubuntu Budgie 17.04 on my desktop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/912044/cant-install-ubuntu-ubuntu-budgie-17-04-on-my-desktop?noredirect=1#comment1435973_912044))...

I'm having more problems post-installation. Whether the issues are related is beyond me.

I get the [following messages at boot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Hit8.jpg). I get the same messages booting from a live usb. I cannot get passed the Ubuntu splash screen because of freezing and screen tearing. Occasionally booting into the live usb would result in my mouse and/or keyboard not working.

-Intel i5-6500

-ASRock Z170M Pro4S

-Nvidia GTX1060

What do these messages tell me, and can it be resolved?